# Error: Could not find or load main class (double click)

Tags: java, jar, double-click

I've just made a "runnable .jar" (or a normal .jar, where I set off manifest on my own. I tryed both)  file from my java app with Eclipse.

When I try to open it by double click, i get this message: "could not find or load main class"

From Command Prompt I can run it with 'java -jar xy.jar'.
Works without any problems.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your manifest file contains the main-class. Like this.

Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

You may want to let eclipse make your manifest just so you can see what it does, then save that manifest file and use it going forward. Also check the class path. You can specify that in the manifest also.

[Here's a link to how to set the entry point in the manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

You may also need to put the classpath in your manifest.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

That can be found here: [Adding classpath to manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Then how can I run with Command Prompt?

The .jar can run... so the manifest must be fine too isn't it?

Or there's no connection? (double-click vs. java -jar xy.jar)

Comment: I think the command line works because of the java -jar command. I think Windows is where you have an issue with the Manifest. I had the same problems when I learned this stuff. The double click run parts is pretty much controlled by the manifest. I think you just need the main class and maybe classpath. Classpath in the manifest is mainly important if you have other jars you depend on. You can list them in the manifest and it will pick them up automatically.

Comment: Maybe the difference is the jar command knows how to run a jar, but a "runnable" jar doesn't know how to run one, because it just uses the "java.exe" command. You could have a shortcut that calls java.exe and passes it the -jar command, but that's extra work. Using the manifest eliminates that, plus you can put other options in it. I put any other command line options my application needs in the manifest like specifying where the helpfile is when I use the JavaHelp api.

Comment: I've tried many different way, but it doesn't work... :(
I see, that the problem will be the "-jar" parameter, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: My MANIFEST is:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main

I've tried the program on Windows XP, where it works by double-click
On Win 7 it works only if i use Command Prompt.

What else should I do with the MANIFEST?
It's just a simple program with some simple class.

Comment: Can you check your file associations in Windows for a jar file. Make sure it's pointing to the correct version of java. Sometimes you can use javaw.exe and sometimes just java.exe, but make sure your file association in Windows 7 is pointing to the java version you expect it to. That's strange that Windows 7 would work different like that. The only thing I think that could be is the classpath in windows may be different. In the classpath of the manifest file put a . for the current path also.